# Property 'Provider' does not exist on type '() => string'.ts(2339)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

when i export and utilize my `context` I am getting un error as :

`Property 'Provider' does not exist on type '() => string'.ts(2339)`.

the idea here is to used the `context` as a service where it's required. so the context function placed separately and imported where it needs. But throw the error.

any one highlight me the missed part please?

here is my context:

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react"; 
export const TabContext = <A extends unknown | null>() => {
  const useTabsActionContext = createContext<A | undefined>(undefined);
  const useTabsContext = () => {
    const ctx = useContext(useTabsActionContext);
    if (ctx === undefined) {
      throw new Error("invalid");
    }
    return ctx;
  };
  return [useTabsActionContext, useTabsContext] as const;
};
```

when I use:

```
import { Dispatch, ReactNode, SetStateAction } from "react";
import { TabContext } from "./tabContext";

export type ActiveTab = string;
export type SetActiveTab = Dispatch<SetStateAction<ActiveTab>>;

const [useTabsActionContext, TabsActionContext] = TabContext<ActiveTab>();
const [useTabsContext, TabsContext] = TabContext<SetActiveTab>();

export { useTabsActionContext, useTabsContext };

export interface TabsProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

function Tabs(props: TabsProps) {
  const { children } = props;
  return (
    <TabsActionContext.Provider> //error
      <TabsContext.Provider>{children}</TabsContext.Provider> //error
    </TabsActionContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default Tabs;
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-on-hooks-1ux4ci?file=/src/components/tabs/Tabs.tsx)

Comment: `TabContext` returns first the context and then the value of that context as parsed by `useContext`. When you consume it in your `Tabs` component, you are trying to to treat the value of the context as a context. Ref: https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useContext#usecontext

Answer (score 1):

as per Henrik, when i swapped the value, it works fine.

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";
    
    export const TabContext = <A extends unknown | null>() => {
      const useTabsActionContext = createContext<A | undefined>(undefined);
      const useTabsContext = () => {
        const ctx = useContext(useTabsActionContext);
        if (ctx === undefined) {
          throw new Error("invalid");
        }
        return ctx;
      };
      return [useTabsContext, useTabsActionContext] as const;
    };
```

thanks